# Improving Django Application Performance: Comparing Blocking and Non-blocking Implementations

Tags: python, django, benchmarking, nonblocking, daphne

I encountered an unexpected error (apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54)) while load testing my Django application with Apache Benchmark (ab). This error occurs when I increase the load to 50 concurrent requests. Surprisingly, even with 20 concurrent requests, there's no significant performance improvement with non-blocking (Can see same throughput as of blocking)

The application consists of two implementations: one using a blocking approach with the default WSGI development server and the other utilizing a non-blocking asynchronous approach with ASGI and the Daphne server. The blocking implementation relies on synchronous requests with the requests library, while the non-blocking approach utilizes aiohttp within an asynchronous view function. Both implementations aim to make POST requests to an external API endpoint and return responses.
Despite expecting better performance with the asynchronous approach, the error persists and the performance remains stagnant.

I'm seeking insights into the root cause of this error and potential solutions to improve performance under heavier loads. Additionally, any advice on optimizing the asynchronous implementation or suggestions for better load-testing strategies would be greatly appreciated
I'm using ab as a benchmarking tool. The command which I used for benchmarking: `ab -c 50 -n 600 -s 800007 -T application/json "http://127.0.0.1:8001/test"`
Blocking Code:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
import requests as requests
from rest_framework.response import Response


@api_view(['GET'])
def index(request):
    res = make_api_request("http://{host}/v1/completions")
    print("blocking response is ---->", res)
    return Response(res, status=200)


def make_api_request(url, method="POST", headers=None, params=None, json_data=None, timeout=None):
    try:
        json_data =  {'prompt': 'Hi, How are you?', 'max_new_tokens': 700, 'temperature': 0.1, 'top_p': 1, 'max_tokens': 700, 'model': 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'}

        response = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, params=params, json=json_data, timeout=timeout)
        return response
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
        raise TimeoutError(f"Request timed out. The server did not respond within the specified timeout period.")
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        raise ConnectionError(f"Request error: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Exception error: {str(e)}")
```

Non Blocking Code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import logging
from rest_framework.response import Response
from adrf.decorators import api_view
import json

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


@api_view(['GET'])
async def index(request):
    # logger.info(f"is async: {iscoroutinefunction(index)}")
    res = await make_api_request("http://{{host}}/v1/completions")
    logger.info("res is ----> %s", res)
    return Response(res, status=200)


async def make_api_request(url, method="POST", headers=None, params=None, json_data=None, timeout=None):
    try:
        json_data =  {'prompt': 'Hi, How are you?', 'max_new_tokens': 700, 'temperature': 0.1, 'top_p': 1, 'max_tokens': 700, 'model': 'meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf'}

        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            async with session.request(method, url, headers=headers, params=params, json=json_data,
                                       timeout=timeout, ssl=False) as response:
                content = await response.read()
                if 'json' in response.headers.get('Content-Type', ''):
                    content = json.loads(content)
                return content
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError("Request timed out. The server did not respond within the specified timeout period.")
    except aiohttp.ClientError as e:
        raise ConnectionError(f"Request error: {str(e)}")
    except Exception as e:
        raise Exception(f"Exception error: {str(e)}")
```

Comment: The default WSGI server (`runserver`) is not suitable for any production use, and it shouldn't be benchmarked.

Comment: @AKX I'm running it in my local(Mac M1).

Comment: Sure, but there is no point benchmarking it. Try running your app with e.g. `gunicorn` with, say, 10 workers.

Comment: @AKX I'm trying to compare the performance of a blocking view with a non-blocking view. For non-blocking I'm using asgi daphne server.

Comment: To what end? I'd imagine the majority of time is spent on the remote end getting the completion, and in a production environment you'd have multiple workers (be they processes, threads, coroutines) so a single request won't block your entire application. Anyway, if you want to save some time, don't build a requests or aiohttp session for every request but reuse one.

Comment: @AKX I'm just doing it for POC purposes for my understanding and please don't mix it up with production. The performance I'm trying to measure is throughput. In this non-blocking io setup, the total number of accepted requests per second should increase as it runs on the concept of event loop. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: How long does it take for a single request to `http://{{host}}/v1/completions` to complete? As I said above, my guess is that that's bottlenecking you, and trying to optimize things around it by using async is basically a fool's errand.

Comment: @AKX It takes 2s and max of 5 QPS. But if you remove the API call part, and try it with time.sleep(2) in blocking and await asyncio.sleep(2) in non-blocking. Still the throughput remains the same.

Comment: Yes, as is expected. All of the stuff that happens _around_ the thing that takes 2 seconds is peanuts compared to, well, 2 seconds.

Comment: Okay. But why I'm getting apr_socket_recv: Connection reset by peer (54) with concurrency of 50 in blocking where as it's working fine in non-blocking.

Comment: Because, as said in my very first comment, `runserver` is not suitable for production or benchmarking use, because it's not a robust server.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. But where can I see the logs that wsgi development server is rejecting the requests rather than queueing the requests.

Comment: I don't think there are such logs for the development server that you're not using for its intended purpose.

Comment: Understood. Will try to run benchmarking with uWSGI. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- You should not benchmark the Django `runserver` development server; it's not meant for heavy load. If you need to benchmark a WSGI app, use e.g. `gunicorn` or `uwsgi` to serve the app instead.
- If you want to compare the performance of a synchronous server to an asynchronous one, be sure to configure the synchronous server to also have enough workers; otherwise it's not a level playing ground at all.
- Since the remote call takes 2 seconds, changing the surrounding code to be faster or `async` won't help much with per-request throughput.

  - `async` code with an async application server does mean that a single async worker can process multiple requests concurrently (when the requests are awaiting for e.g. the aforementioned remote call).